# PC-Lint Misra 10.1 Error on Boolean Expression

Tags: c, lint, misra, pc-lint

PC-Lint version 9.00L looks at this code:

```
  typedef unsigned char boolean_t; //This is actually in a system header file.
  ...
  /* The rest is in the .c file I'm working on. */
  boolean_t booleanVal
  ...
  uint8_t maskedVal;
  maskedVal = 0; //real code has this assigned based on a bitwise-and
  booleanVal = ( maskedVal != 0U );
```

And gives this error:

```
booleanVal = ( maskedVal != 0U );
                                ^
"LINT: <filename> Note 960: Violates MISRA 2004 
Required Rule 10.1, Implicit conversion of integer to smaller type"
```

I have declared boolean_t as a strong Boolean type using `-strong(B, boolean_t )` in my .lnt file.

So why is PC-Lint complaining about converting integers when I'm assigning a clearly boolean expression to a clearly boolen variable?

Comment: Is it because you insist that `0` is `unsigned int` with `0U` yet compare it with `uint8_t`?

Comment: You seem to be freely mixing `unsigned char` with `uint8_t` and isn't this kind of sloppiness one of the things that MISRA tries to prevent? They are not necessarily the same type.

Comment: Aren't "booleans" in C just typedef'd ints?

Comment: @cHao Only if you have been living under a rock since the year 1999. But yeah boolean expressions such as `!=` yield `int` still, and not `bool` as in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of `( maskedVal != 0U )` is `int` yet even though it is `0` or `1` MISRA complains that it is being forced into the smaller `unsigned char` your homebrew boolean type.

Don't invent your own boolean type. Either use `int` or the formal boolean type available in modern C implementations.

Comment: Thanks!  The typedef wasn't my invention, it came from one of the system include files from the MCU vendor, and silly me thought that I could trust the vendor =).  Luckily the compiler does have a `bool` type, and changing to that type gets me past this.

Answer (score 2):

MISRA-C:2004 didn't treat boolean types as a special case, they were just another small integer type like `char` etc. Notably, it did not support `bool` either since it didn't support C99.

All if this was fixed in MISRA-C:2012, where your home-brewed type would be so-called *essentially boolean*. There's no requirement in MISRA-C:2012 that you must use `bool`, although this is recommended, but the guidelines tolerate the use of "home-brewed booleans", given that you can somehow tell your static analyser which type it is.

But since you are using an older version of MISRA-C, `booleanVal = ( maskedVal != 0U );` is an assignment to narrower type from `int`, and also from a signed type to an unsigned type.

This is a violation of MISRA-C:2004 rule 10.1, but perfectly fine in MISRA-C:2012.

Notably, you also have an implicit promotion from `uint8_t` to `unsigned int`, although that shouldn't violate any MISRA rule.